# Shell script to wait till the command execute and status change

Tags: bash, shell, openstack, openstack-cinder

I am creating a shell script to Backup openstack cinder volume to glance image as like below.

test1 is volume name in the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
BACKUPDIR=/mnt/osbk/
declare -a VMS=(
    test1
)
source /root/admin-openrc
echo $DATE `date` Starting Backup process of images
for vmname in "${VMS[@]}"
do
    echo Backing up $vmname
    echo cinder upload-to-image ${vmname} ${vmname}-vol-bkp --disk-format qcow2 --container-format bare --force True
    cinder upload-to-image ${vmname} ${vmname}-vol-bkp --disk-format qcow2 --container-format bare --force True
    echo glance image-download ${vmname}-vol-bkp --file $BACKUPDIR/${vmname}-vol-bkp-${DATE}.qcow2
    glance --os-image-api-version 1  image-download ${vmname}-vol-bkp --file $BACKUPDIR/${vmname}-vol-bkp-${DATE}.qcow2
done
```

Output looks like this:

```
2018-12-29 Sat Dec 29 16:37:45 IST 2018 Starting Backup process of images
Backing up test1
cinder upload-to-image test1 test1-vol-bkp --disk-format qcow2 --container-format bare --force True
+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Property            | Value                                |
+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
| container_format    | bare                                 |
| disk_format         | qcow2                                |
| display_description |                                      |
| id                  | 26c90209-8151-4136-b5de-f2ad7419b100 |
| image_id            | 01e88175-a3fa-4354-8c0f-e4fafd9c9fc3 |
| image_name          | test1-vol-bkp                        |
| is_public           | False                                |
| protected           | False                                |
| size                | 2                                    |
| status              | uploading                            |
| updated_at          | 2018-12-29T11:07:00.000000           |
| volume_type         | None                                 |
+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
glance image-download test1-vol-bkp --file /mnt/osbk//test1-vol-bkp-2018-12-29.qcow2
404 Not Found
The resource could not be found.
Image 01e88175-a3fa-4354-8c0f-e4fafd9c9fc3 is not active (HTTP 404)
```

From above output the status is uploading...

I need to hold my script to wait or check the status of volume change to Active, then only the glance image download command has to run.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can use the `wait` command. It will force the next line to be executed only after all the previous commands finish. Is it enough to solve your problem?

Comment: There must be some command that tells you the status without uploading anything - please add that command and an example of its output. Then the answer is simple.

Comment: Yes, give a way to reproduce your situation to help you.